# Split multiple of the same file by date and choose the file with the latest date

Tags: python

I have a list of `.xlsx` file names that have a date attached to the end just before the file extension, for example `JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx`. I have multiple of these file names in the list but I need only the filename with the latest date attached to the end. So I could have a file that is `JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx` and then another file name in the list that is `JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx`. I only want the file name with the latest date. Anything else I want to drop from the list.

Below is a shortened list of files I am working with:

```
    files = ['JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx','JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx','DAG_- 
              -_USA_2019-01-31.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-06-01.xlsx']
```

So far what I have tried is creating a regex to split the date and the beginning part of the file into separate lists("matches" and "dates"). The regex works properly for splitting the file in two. After that I am lost on what to do in order to get only the files I need. I don't even know if regex is right way to go at this point. I sorted the list in descending order because it would put the latest date for that group of files at the beginning of the file sequence.

```
files = ['JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx','JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx','DAG_- 
          -_USA_2019-01-31.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-06-01.xlsx']

files.sort(reverse=True)
matches = []
dates = []
for file in files:
    match = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\_([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*|--))(\_[a-zA- 
    Z]*)* (\_[a-zA-Z]+_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', file)
    date = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}',file)
    matches.append(match.group(0))
    dates.append(date.group(0))
```

I expect to only have a list of two files with the closest date to today. See below:

```
new_list = ['JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-06-01.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just taking a simple parsing approach since the file name structure seems pretty stable.

Something like this:

```
files = ['JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx','JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-01-31.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-06-01.xlsx']

dates = [(name.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0], i) for i, name in enumerate(files)] # split filename as such since its consistent, record indices also

dates.sort(reverse=True)

# index into files to get full name, this should give you the most recent file
print files[dates[0][1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date string to datetime object, and use it's properties to sort the list.:

```
from datetime import datetime

def extract_date(file_name):
    date_str = file_name[-15:-5]
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')

files = ['JAK_--_USA_2019-01-07.xlsx','JAK_--_USA_2019-01-08.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-01-31.xlsx','DAG_--_USA_2019-06-01.xlsx']

print(sorted(files, key=extract_date))
```

After the list is sorted you can extract elements that you are interested in.

Function extract_date will work if the file name format is exactly as you mentioned. If it's not, you can put some of your regex code in this function, and it should also work.